# App Suspend IIS app pool .Net 4.5.1

Tags: .net, iis

i just read a blog in msdn that .Net 4.5.1 introduces the new app pool setting App Suspend.  In what circumstance you want to set your app pool to "Suspend" rather than "Terminate" or vice versa?   if the "Suspend" idle mode is the much better setting than Terminate, then why not defaulting to Suspend and get rid of the "Terminate" idle mode.

Comment: You'd probably be better off on SF with your question.

Comment: any comments out there?

Answer (score 12):

IIS version 6 and above uses Application Pools to serve websites. Each App Pool is basically a separate worker process that will respond to requests for whatever websites you have in that App Pool. It helps to isolate different websites from each other (resource usage, errors, security breaches, etc).

**Part of the way Application Pools are structured, they are by default "recycled" or restarted every so often to avoid application crashes or reset memory leaks.**

There are three main ways that cause an App Pool to recycle:

1. Interval-based (by default it's set to every 29 hours)
2. Unresponsive (measured by IIS checking the app performance)
3. Config changes (changing web.config or app pool settings)

Recycling isn't a big deal because IIS will create a new process and transfer requests before terminating the old process so there's no gap in serving requests. **However, there is a setting for the App Pools that will terminate the process completely if there are no requests for a certain amount of time (default of 20 mins).**

When the app pool shuts down and a new request comes in, then there's a noticeable lag of several seconds for the worker process to start, load the .NET frameworks, compile any pages in your app and finally serve the request. This is referred to as a "cold start" and can create a bad experience for your users.

You can disable both the recycle settings and the timeout-based terminate options if you want (and I do for several big applications) **but if you are running lots of sites on a single server that don't get a lot of continuous traffic, you can conserve resources by using the new "Suspend" option.**

**Instead of completely terminating the process, IIS instead moves it to a very low-memory state.** This way if a new request does come in, your app starts up instantly. There's no lag. But when there's no traffic, it uses just a tiny fraction of memory and no CPU so there's no overhead on your server.

**It's really meant for shared environments with servers running lots of sites.** If you have constant traffic you won't notice a difference since the App Pools never stop anyway but if you're sticking to the default settings then I highly recommend setting the App Pools to Suspend mode. **Note that this requires both Windows Server 2012 R2 and .NET 4.5.1 to work.**

Here's a Youtube video explaining it further from the Visual Studio team:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXw5gyqTxoo

Comment: still not getting the answer! if you are hosting your site on dedicated physical machine and only one website app and one dedicated app pool,  why don't you set the app pool to Suspend ?

Comment: It's already been answered: 
- If you have constant traffic the app pool won't stop.
- If you don't have constant traffic, then you can disable the timeout setting so that the app pool doesn't stop.
- However, if you don't have constant traffic AND you leave the timeout setting enabled, then the app pool will shutdown completely when set to "terminate" and this makes a new request to the site much slower. Setting it to "suspend" will avoid this complete shutdown so new requests don't take so long. 

There's no reason not to set it on "suspend" if the option is available.

Comment: just an aside as the post mentions that windows server 2012 R2 and .net 4.5.1 is required, in fact it's a feature of IIS8.5 (so if you have IIS 8.0, you wahnt have the option...) check this :http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/idle-worker-process-page-out-in-iis85

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 comes with IIS 8.5.